# jQuery 'not' function giving spurious results

Tags: javascript, jquery

Made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n6ub3/

I'm aware that the code has a LOT of repeating in it, its on the list to refactor once functionality is correct.

The behaviour i'm trying to achieve is if there is no selectedTab on page load, set the first tab in each group to selectedTab. If there is a selectedTab present, then use this as the default shown div.

However, as you can see from the fiddle its not working as planned!

If anyone has any ideas how to refactor this code down that'd be great also!

Comment: Please show your relevant code.

Comment: I don't understand. There is a fiddle link and all of the code is relevant

Comment: Daniel means "make a testcase - this is not rentacoder.com"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [WORKING DEMO with simplified code](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/n6ub3/8/)

```
$('.tabContent').hide();

$('.tabs').each(function(){
    var search = $(this).find('div.selectedTab').length;
    if( search === 0){
        $(this).find('.tabTrigger').eq(0).addClass('selectedTab')
    }

    var selectedIndex = $(this).find('.selectedTab').index();
    $(this).find('.tabContent').eq(selectedIndex).show();
});

$('.tabTrigger').click(function(){
   var ind = $(this).index();
    $(this).addClass('selectedTab').siblings().removeClass('selectedTab');
   $(this).parent().find('.tabContent').eq(ind).fadeIn(700).siblings('.tabContent').hide();   
});
```

That's all! You don't need all that ID's all around. Look at the demo!

Comment: Great! Glad you like it! If you have questions ... just ask!

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
 if($('.tabs1 .tabTrigger:not(.selectedTab)')){
                $('.tabs1 .tabTrigger:first').addClass('selectedTab');
        }
```

to

```
if ( !$('.tabs1 .tabTrigger.selectedTab').length ) {
    $('.tabs1 .tabTrigger:first').addClass('selectedTab');
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/n6ub3/1/

---

They way you are doing it (*the first code part*) you are adding the `.selectedTab` class if **there is at least one** of the tabs in that group that is not selected at start .. (*that means always*)

---

**Update**

For a shortened version look at http://jsfiddle.net/n6ub3/7/

Answer (score 1):

Your selector are doing exactly what you're writing them for.

`$('.tabs3 .tabTrigger:not(.selectedTab)')` is true has long as there is at least one tab that has not the selected tab (so always true in your test case).

So you should change the logic to `!$('.tabs3 .tabTrigger.selectedTab').length` which is true only if there are no selectedTab

Answer (score 0):

With a couple of very minor changes you code can be reduced to:

```
$('.tabContent').hide();

$('.tabs').each(function(){
    if($('.tabTrigger.selectedTab',$(this)).length < 1)
        $('.tabTrigger:first').addClass('selectedTab');
});

$('.tabTrigger').click(function(){
   var content = $(this).data('content');
   $(this).parents('div').children('.tabContent').hide();
   $(this).parents('div').children('.tabTrigger').removeClass('selectedTab');
   $(this).addClass('selectedTab');
   $('#' + content).show();
});


$('.tabTrigger.selectedTab').click();
```

Those changes are

1. Change the class on the surrounding `div` to just `class="tabs`.
2. Add a `data-content` attribute with the name of the associated content div

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/gsTBQ/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm a bit behind the times obviously; but, here's my updated version of your demo...

I have updated your fiddle as in the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4y3Xp/1/.

Basically I just tidied it up a bit, and to refactor I put everything in a separate function instead of having each of the cases in their own.  This is basically just putting a new function in that does similar to what yours was doing (e.g. not modifying your HTML model), but I tried to clean it up a bit, and I also just made a function that took the tab number and did each of the items that way rather than needing a separate copy for each.

The main issue with the 'not' part of your query is that the function doesn't return a boolean; like all JQuery queries, it's returning all matching nodes. I just updated that part to return whether .selected was returning more than 0 results; if not, I go ahead and call the code to select the first panel.

Glad you got your problem resolved :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var HandleOne = function (i) {
    var idxString = i.toString();
    var tabName = '.tabs' + idxString;
    var tabContent = tabName + ' .tabContent';

    $(tabContent).hide();

    var hasSelected = $(tabName + ' .tabTrigger.selectedTab').length > 0;
    if (!hasSelected)
        $(tabName + ' .tabTrigger:first').addClass('selectedTab');

    var selectedTabId = 
        $(tabName + ' .tabTrigger.selectedTab').attr('id');

    var selectedContentId = selectedTabId.replace('tab','content');
    $('#' + selectedContentId).show();

    $(tabName + ' .tabTrigger').click(function() {
        $(tabName + ' .tabTrigger').removeClass('selectedTab');
        $(tabName + ' .tabContent').hide();

        $(this).addClass('selectedTab');
        var newContentId = $(this).attr('id').replace('tab','content');
        $('#' + newContentId).show();
    });
}

HandleOne(1);
HandleOne(2);
HandleOne(3);
});
```